# Is it necessary to add a web reference for a web service created inside the same web project in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, vs-web-application-project

Is it necessary to add a web reference for a web service created inside the same web project in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you want to consume it in your project as a web-service.

Since your web-service class is also a regular class, you could call the web methods directly without a proxy.

Your web-service in this case would only server to expose the needed functionality to consumers.